# c++ header inclusion order with conditional compilation

Tags: c++, compilation, header

Say I have two files A.hpp and B.hpp

A.hpp:

```
#indef DEF_A
#define DEF_A

class A{
    /*implementation of class A*/
    /*some part of it needs B*/
    #ifdef DEF_B
        void method(B b){/*do something with B*/}
    #endif
}
#endif
```

B.hpp:

```
#indef DEF_B
#define DEF_B

class B{
    /*implementation of class B*/
    /*some part of it needs A*/
    #ifdef DEF_A
        void method(A a){/*do something with A*/}
    #endif
}
#endif
```

I don't want to inclue A.hpp in B.hpp (or vice-versa) because then every time I need A.hpp I will need B.hpp (or vice-versa).

But when in the main file I write :

main.cpp

```
#include"A.hpp"
#include"B.hpp"

int main(){
    A a;
    B b;
}
```

`A::method(B b)` is unknown. If I reverse the inclusion order I will only have `B::method(A a)`.

Is there a way to have access to both methods when the two headers are included ?

[edit]
The method should also work for template class with no .cpp file.
[/edit]

Comment: Why don't use forward declaration (and pass argument by const reference) ? (And move implementation in *A.cpp* and *B.cpp*)

Comment: @Jarod42 what happens if I never define a forwarded class ? And with template class?

Comment: You can't use its definition. (so you can't do `A a;` for example).

Comment: @Jarod42 Okay, that seems nice. Could I write `a.some_method()` `B::method(A const& a)`?

Answer (score 2):

I would use forward declaration, something like:

**A.hpp**

```
#indef DEF_A
#define DEF_A

class B; // Forward declaration of B

class A { // Definition of A
public:
    void method(const B& b);
};
#endif
```

**A.cpp**

```
#include "A.hpp"
#include "B.hpp"

void A::method(const B& b) { /* your implementation */ }
```

**B.hpp**

```
#indef DEF_B
#define DEF_B

class A; // Forward declaration of A

class B { // Definition of B
public:
    void method(const A& a);
};
#endif
```

**B.cpp**

```
#include "B.hpp"
#include "A.hpp"

void B::method(const A& a) { /* your implementation */ }
```

And then in **main.cpp**
you include both *A.hpp* and *B.hpp* as you use both of them.
But if in C.cpp you use only A (without B) you can do

**C.cpp**

```
#include "A.hpp"

void foo()
{
    A a;
    // B b; // If uncommented, that would fail to compile.
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer but I see some problems/questions... 1) for template class where you don't have a .cpp file, this method won't work. 2) I guess that if I include the two files .hpp in the A.cpp and B.cpp, I will still need to provide all files to compile the code

Comment: 1) For template class, you have to include both files.

Comment: 2) If you want to share file A.cpp between different projects whereas one project doesn't use `B`, you may still add a new define `USE_B` to conditionally include relevant part (but don't rely on include guard `DEF_B` which may break your code depending of order of include).

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should give the [pimpl-idiom](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/making-pimpl-easy/205918714?pgno=2) a try. You could easily hide the implementation details in .cpp file, even if its about a templated classes:

```
//Important: fwd declaration as Jarod42 already stated!
class B;
class AImpl;

class A
{
   void aMethod( B* b )
   {
      impl->( b );
   }
   AImpl* impl; //this will work because compiler need not to know
                //exact object size as we are creating a pointer or
                //reference...type definition in cpp
}

// same here for B;
//in cpp file of A and B:

class AImpl : public TemplateClass<X>
{
   void aMethod( B* b ){}
};
```

I hope this will help you with your problem!